# Parse JSON into HStack with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui

I've quite given up on this as I can't find a solution no matter what I do.

JSON: https://github.com/MasonD3V/evoflight/raw/master/featuredapps.json

There are no errors in the build, but I am brought with this error in the console after launching the app:

**Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)): file EvoFlight/FeaturedAPICall.swift, line 14**

Here is a look at my code so you can understand it.

- Snippets from main class

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    ...
    
    @State var featuredApps: [FeaturedApps] = []
    
    var body: some View {
    
        ForEach(featuredApps) { app in
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                    
            }
        }

    .onAppear() {
            featureApiCall().getApps { (app) in
                self.featuredApps = app
            }
        }

struct FeaturedApps: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    
    let image: String
    let name: String
    let category: String
    let ipa: String
}
```

- FeaturedAPICall.swift

```swift
class featureApiCall {
    func getApps(completion:@escaping ([FeaturedApps]) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://github.com/MasonD3V/evoflight/raw/master/featuredapps.json") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            let users = try! JSONDecoder().decode([FeaturedApps].self, from: data!)
            print(users)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(users)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

TLDR: Getting an "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead" error and I've gone through several attempts to fix it.

EDIT: I've applied a few recommended changes. Here is the code now.

```swift
// ContentView Code

struct ContentView: View {

    ...
    
    @State var featuredApps: FeaturedAppsWrapper
    
    var body: some View {
    
        ForEach(featuredApps.apps) { app in
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                                    
            }
        }

    .onAppear() {
            featureApiCall().getApps { (app) in
                self.featuredApps = app
            }
        }

struct FeaturedApps: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    
    let image: String
    let name: String
    let category: String
    let ipa: String
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView() // Missing argument for parameter 'featuredApps' in call error
    }
}

struct FeaturedAppsWrapper :Codable {
    var apps : [FeaturedApps]
    
    init() {
        
    }
    
}

struct FeaturedApps: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    
    let image: String
    let name: String
    let category: String
    let ipa: String
    
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case image, name, category, ipa
    }
}

// FeaturedApiCall.swift
class featureApiCall {
    func getApps(completion:@escaping (FeaturedAppsWrapper) -> ()) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://github.com/MasonD3V/evoflight/raw/master/featuredapps.json") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            do {
                let wrapper = try JSONDecoder().decode(FeaturedAppsWrapper.self, from: data!)
                let users = wrapper.apps
                print(users)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

1. Your model is missing a layer. Your JSON has an `apps` key that contains the `FeaturedApps`, but nothing in your models reflects that. I've used `FeaturedAppsWrapper`.
2. Because the `id` isn't present in the JSON, you need to tell the compiler to use certain `CodingKeys`, excluding `id`.

```
struct FeaturedAppsWrapper :Codable {
    var apps : [FeaturedApps]
}

struct FeaturedApps: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    
    let image: String
    let name: String
    let category: String
    let ipa: String
    
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case image, name, category, ipa
    }
}

do {
    let wrapper = try JSONDecoder().decode(FeaturedAppsWrapper.self, from: data!)
    let users = wrapper.apps
    print(users)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Lastly, you it might be a good idea to get out of the habit of using `!` to force unwrap and to `try` -- it will guarantee a crash if something goes wrong. I've used `do/try/catch`, for example, to get rid of the `try!`

---

Given your updates, here's how I would approach it:

```
struct FeaturedAppsWrapper :Codable {
    var apps : [FeaturedApps]
}

struct FeaturedApps: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    
    let image: String
    let name: String
    let category: String
    let ipa: String
    
    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case image, name, category, ipa
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var apiManager = ApiManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(apiManager.featuredApps.apps) { app in
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                Text(app.name)
            }
        }
        
        .onAppear() {
            apiManager.getApps()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

class ApiManager : ObservableObject {
    @Published var featuredApps = FeaturedAppsWrapper(apps: [])
    
    func getApps() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://github.com/MasonD3V/evoflight/raw/master/featuredapps.json") else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            do {
                let wrapper = try JSONDecoder().decode(FeaturedAppsWrapper.self, from: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.featuredApps = wrapper
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        .resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: you can also do this: `let id = UUID()` (not var) and skip the CodingKeys.

Comment: @jnpdx i have given what you said a shot and now remain with "Missing argument for parameter 'featuredApps' in call" in my preview provider. I'm guessing I had messed up somewhere stating something in my code.

Comment: update your question with the code you are using now, including the preview code.

Comment: Nothing that I did should affect your preview. Do be clear, my “ “do” block should appear where you are using try!  I agree with the above comment to update your question with the preview and your edits if this is unclear.

Comment: I don't have time to review all of the edits -- there's a lot of new information. I'll say that you aren't using your completion handler at all. Also, instead of returning the wrapper, return the `users` property of it. Then, you can go back to having an empty array for your initial `@State` value.

Comment: I can update more tomorrow when I have more time if you can't figure out how to make the adjustments

Comment: try this: `@State var featuredApps = FeaturedAppsWrapper(apps: [])` instead of `@State var featuredApps: FeaturedAppsWrapper`

Comment: @workingdog i've given that attempt already and it moves the error to the State, "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

Comment: That’s because you defined an empty init. You can get rid of that. In fact, I’m surprised it even compiles.

Comment: See my update -- I've shown you how to put the pieces together given your update.

Comment: @Mason if this resolved your issue, can you accept it using the green checkmark, please?